# Curret mirror with discrete BJTs?

Tags: bjt, current-source, current-mirror

I need to supply power for some power diodes. The power supply units are current regulated, the diodes are connected in series. 
Let's say that i hve 3 strips of leds, each one needs 400mA, around 20V +/- 2V and one power supply providing a regulated source of 1200mA max 40V.
Is it possible to make a current mirror using discrete bjts ( not IC )? 
Can i expect to have mismatches (due to the BJTs tolerances ) lower than 50mA ? 
How much difference between the strips crrent i should expect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Matched transistor pairs are readily available; is there a reason you can't use those?

Comment: why would you need a mirror in the first place? That does not seem a good design choice to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible to do this.  In fact, it is done quite often in old test equipment.  However, it can be difficult to get this to work right as the transistor gains have to be very precisely matched.  This is easy to do on a chip as the transistors are physically close to each other and as a result will be built with similar characteristics as well as being thermally connected, but with discrete transistors this is much more difficult.  For one, you will need to make sure that the transistors are at the same temperature by physically connecting the cases together.  Second, you may need to get a box of transistors and swap them out until you find some with similar current gains.

Comment: Ok but my requiremens are not so strict, i don't need a precise matching.
If i pick two random transistors , do you think that the difference could exceed the 20% of the wanted current ?

Comment: Dunno.  They're not really designed to be used like that, the current gains can vary significantly.  Possibly by more than 20%.  The current gain is not precisely controlled as most transistors are supposed to be used either for switching or in a closed loop where the feedback determines the gain.

Comment: And what if i use MOSFETs?

Comment: You're going to have the same issue with either a BJT or a MOSFET.  The gain of the individual components are highly temperature and process dependent, so you will have to match them manually.